# Need some public API to get status of an Instance

Tags: instance, actionstatus, status

I need to pull up the information regarding some instances, whether they are currently available, Performance Degradation, Service Disruption or under maintenance, along with the cause (if any). I also need information for any upcoming events or any incident raised.

We need some API to get this data. It is although available on the [public Salesforce Status site](https://status.salesforce.com/status/NA47) but we need to put this data in internal our dashboard.

Comment: maybe you can try to parse rss ? https://status.salesforce.com/rss/NA47